# subdomain external html page checks wordpress if user is logged in

Tags: php, html, wordpress, session

Is there a way to have a HTML page on a sub domain check the if user is logged in on the main domain word press.

Something like:
if user is logged in check the word press cookies or something so I can do an else statement stating that the person needs to be logged in on main site before they can view this sub domain sign up page for purchasing subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Make sure you set COOKIE_DOMAIN to ".maindomain", e.g. ".yoursite.com", otherwise you will not be able to access it from the subdomain. E.g. a cookie from "www.yoursite.com" is by default not accessible from "other.yoursite.com".